# Vue DevTools could detect Vue.js but does not show in F12 panel

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to debug a webpage written in Vue. I want to look into the Vue data using Vue DevTools. I installed it on Chrome and it could detect my webpage :
[image]

However when I Click F12 to open the DevTools, the Vue tab could not appear on panel:
[image]

I also tried to install VUE devtools locally (downloaded from github, using npm run build) and had the same result. 
Any suggestions for solving this issue?

Comment: Debugging has to be enabled. If the developers disabled debugging, then the extension will show that the page uses Vue,  but you won't be able to debug and see the details through the devtools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The possible reason maybe vue devtools can't detect vue code, you can test it by https://vuejs.org/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Change the vue source `<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>`
to `<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>` could solve this issue